# Select from a choice of madlib sentences python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to write a Madlibs game where the user can pick one of three sentences to play with. I am able to get this to work when using just one but I tried to implement a loop to assign a sentence choice and this is where the problem starts!

```
#Sentences for THE GREAT SENTENCE CREATION GAME
sentence_a = """My best memory has to be when MUSICIAN and I
            PAST_TENSE_VERB through a game of SPORT. Then we
            listened to GENRE_OF_MUSIC with PERSON. It was insane!!"""

sentence_b = """Did you know, MUSICIAN once PAST_TENSE_VERB on a
            OBJECT for NUMBER hours. Not many people know that!"""

sentence_c = """GENRE_OF_MUSIC was created by PERSON in Middle Earth.
            We only know GENRE_OF_MUSIC because NUMBER years ago,
            MUSICIAN went on an epic quest with only a OBJECT for
            company. MUSICIAN had tosteal GENRE_OF_MUSIC from PERSON
            and did this by playing a game of SPORT as a distraction."""
#GAME START

def get_sentence():
    choice = ""
    while choice not in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
        choice = raw_input("select your sentence: a, b, or c: ")
        if choice == "a":
            return sentence_a
        elif choice == "b":
            return sentence_b
        elif choice == "c":
            return sentence_c
        else:
            print("Invalid choice...")

#Words to be replaced
parts_of_speech = ["MUSICIAN", "GENRE_OF_MUSIC", "NUMBER",
                "OBJECT", "PAST_TENSE_VERB", "PERSON", "SPORT"]            

# Checks if a word in parts_of_speech is a substring of the word passed in.
def word_in_pos(word, parts_of_speech):
    for pos in parts_of_speech:
        if pos in word:
            return pos
    return None

# Plays a full game of mad_libs. A player is prompted to replace words in ml_string, 
# which appear in parts_of_speech with their own words.  
def play_game(ml_string, parts_of_speech):    
    replaced = []
    ml_string = ml_string.split()
    for word in ml_string:
        replacement = word_in_pos(word, parts_of_speech)
        if replacement != None:
            user_input = raw_input("Type in a: " + replacement + " ")
            word = word.replace(replacement, user_input)
            replaced.append(word)
        else:
            replaced.append(word)
    replaced = " ".join(replaced)
    return replaced

print play_game(sentence_a, parts_of_speech)
```

So the error I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Project.py", line 75, in <module>
    print play_game(get_sentence, parts_of_speech)
  File "Project.py", line 63, in play_game
    ml_string = ml_string.split()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split'
```

But I don't understand it, I'm sure it's something obvious so if anyone could explain a solution I'd be very grateful!!

Comment: Take a look at [ask]. And if you want to add something to your question, just edit the question and add it.

Comment: Can you also fix the indentation? The code as posted isn't going to work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a slight syntax problem you forgot the () on get_sentence to tell it its a function.

```
print play_game(get_sentence(), parts_of_speech)
```

You need () on get_sentence for it to do what you want.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I didn't think it'd be that simple!! I'm make sure to remember that in future. Thanks Reginol_Blindhop!

Comment: @reginol Nice answer.  It deserves a checkmark because the missing `()` was the problem.  But I'd like to give you an upvote as well.  (You can only get one check, but you can get an unlimited number of upvotes, per answer.)  However, I can't, because you say that the () "tells it its a function."  The error message was `'function' object has no attribute split`, so clearly Python knew that this *was* a function.  Could you [edit] your answer to give accurate details about the () and the function?  That way this answer will be accurate for those who read it later.